# Detect if a command is followed by subscript

Tags: macros, subscripts, auto-detection

**New version of the question**

How to detect if a command is being followed by a subscript in a robust manner?

I am using `\newcommand*{\command}[1]{\IfStrEq{#1}{_}{...}{...}}`, and it works, but it is broken by a package called `breqn`.
Is there a more robust way of making the detection without the `xstring` package, say by using `\@ifnextchar` or some other built-in command?

---

**Old version of the question**

I have a command for printing probabilities `$\Prob{X=3}$` as, say just simply `$P(X=3)$` [image: formula], and sometimes I need a long subscript on the `$P$`, like `$${\operatorname*{P}}_{y\sim Y|X}{y=3|x=2}$$`:

[image: formula]

I would like to use the same macro `\Prob` both for `\Prob{X=3}` and `\Prob_{y\sim Y|X}{y=3|x=2}` to keep code consistency.
And I wrote a partially working solution:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*{\Prob}[1]{\IfStrEq{#1}{_}{\ProbWithSub}{\ProbWithoutSub{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\ProbWithSub}[2]{{\operatorname*{P}_{#1}(#2)}}
\newcommand*{\ProbWithoutSub}[1]{{P(#1)}}
```

It seems to works but only if the commands are defined after `\begin{document}`. Otherwise I get the following: [image: formula]

**Why** does this happen, and how should I fix it to define it before `\begin{document}`?

---

**Minimal working example**

While making a minimal working example, I found out that my solution is actually correct but is broken by a package called `breqn`.
Still, I am curious to understand why it breaks, and how to detect the subscript in a robust manner.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{breqn} % Root of the problem

\newcommand{\custom}[1]{(#1)}

\newcommand*{\Prob}[1]{\IfStrEq{#1}{_}{\ProbWithSub}{\ProbWithoutSub{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\ProbWithSub}[2]{{\operatorname*{P}_{#1}\custom{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\ProbWithoutSub}[1]{{P\custom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\XProb}[1]{\IfStrEq{#1}{_}{\XProbWithSub}{\XProbWithoutSub{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\XProbWithSub}[2]{{\operatorname*{P}_{#1}\custom{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\XProbWithoutSub}[1]{{P\custom{#1}}}

These use Prob: $\Prob{X=3}$ and $\Prob_{y\sim Y|X}{y=3|x=5}$.

These use XProb: $\XProb{X=3}$ and $\XProb_{y\sim Y|X}{y=3|x=5}$.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: You could use xparse to create a command with one mandatory argument and one optional, for example: `\NewDocumentCommand{\Prob}{ m o }{\IfValueTF{\ProbWithSub{#1}{#2}}{\ProbWithoutSub{#1}}`

Comment: Is there any reason the macro has to take arguments at all? Couldn't you just write `\Prob(foo)` and `\Prob_{baz}(foo)`? Then `\Prob` would just have to print the symbol (and set up the correct subscript behavior).

Comment: Regarding your literal question: If you provide a complete MWE, people are much more likely to test and try to resolve your problem.

Comment: @schtandard The macro is that simple just for simplifying the question. My actual macro removes spaces around the equals sign among other features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that some LaTeX packages change the catcode of `_` to 12. You can try:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{breqn} % Root of the problem

\begin{document}
Catcode: \the\catcode`_ .
\end{document}
```

and you can see 12. If you remove `\usepackage{breqn}` then you see 8.

So, the comparison `\IfStrEq{#1}{_}` fails becase the first argument is `_` of catcode 12 and the second argument is `_` of catcode 8.

I don't understand LaTeX's `\IfStrEq` macro, so I suggest to do this by TeX primitive `\ifx` followed by the `\detokenize` eTeX primitive which ensures that both following tokens have category 12.

```
\def\Prob #1{\expandafter\ifx\detokenize{_#1}\expandafter\ProbA \else \ProbB{#1}\fi}
\def\ProbA #1#2{\mathop{P{}}_{#1}(#2)}
\def\ProbB #1{P(#1)}
```

Comment: Note that OpTeX sets catcode of `_` to 11 and there is no reason to change it during document processing, so `\ifx _#1` will always work.

Comment: Indeed, this answer works with and without the package `breqn` , and explains the issue.

Comment: Do you know how to extend your code to detect if the next character is underscore but without consuming it? (like `\ifNextIsUnderscore{this}{that}`) I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

Never ever use `$$` in a LaTeX document (it may be used in selected cases to define environments, but that's for experts).

Just define

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Prob}{\mathnormal{P}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Prob}{\mathnormal{P}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Prob(X=3) \\
\Prob_{y\sim Y\mid X}(y=3\mid x=2)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to absorb an argument in order to format it, you can use the `e` specifier to `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Prob}{e{_}m}{%
  \operatorname*{\mathnormal{P}}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}%
  (#2)% other settings here
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Prob{X=3} \\
\Prob_{y\sim Y|X}{y=3\mid x=2}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my actual macro is not just the P(#1). I left it like that for simplicity, but it actually removes spaces around the equals sign among other features. Hence, your solution is useful for this particular case of P(#1), but it does not answer the question of detecting if a command is followed by subscript.

Comment: @CarlosPinzón Added a different version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `e` argument type.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\custom}[1]{(#1)}

\NewDocumentCommand\Prob{e{_}m}{\operatorname*{P}\IfNoValueF{#1}{_{#1}}\custom{#2}}

\begin{document}

These use Prob: $\Prob{X=3}$ and $\Prob_{y\sim Y|X}{y=3|x=5}$.


\end{document}
```